# How to pass data (like TestCase ID, status) from scenario to after scenario

Tags: karate

I have to update the results of each scenario to third party application and to achieve it, i am calling a feature (updateResults.feature) in after scenario. But i dont know how to pass the scenario status(pass, fail) to after scenario.
Note: Using Karate version 0.8.0.RC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example, [`hooks.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/hooks/hooks.feature) you can pass arguments:

```
karate.call('after-scenario.feature', { caller: info.featureFileName });
```

Refer the docs for `karate.call()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-call

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am not sure which object contains the status of scenario (pass/fail) that can be passed to after scenario.

Comment: @TThakur the errorMessage will be not-null if fail, use that

Comment: Do you plan to add scenario status/outcome to ScenarioInfo class in future?

Comment: @TThakur not really

Comment: i am not able to pass any variable from scenario to after-scenario. Am i missing something?

Comment: @TThakur ask a new question

Comment: I am able to pass all the variable of ScenarioInfo as it is instantiated in the js, but unable to pass any variable that is defined in a scenario.

Comment: @TThakur or follow this process https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue